# IinnerHTML with transition/ animation CSS

Tags: javascript, css, css-transitions, css-animations, innerhtml

So I have javascript code:

```
document.getElementById("name").innerHTML =  name ;
```

can I use CSS Transition when innerHTML shows the result? like fade in from right or typing animation like in this link https://codepen.io/rusjames/pen/uAFhE

any suggestion? thanks before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the animation to a class, then give the element the animation class after you update the text with `innerHTML`

```js
var name = 'somebody';
    el = document.getElementById("name");

el.innerHTML =  name;
el.classList.add('type');
```

```css
body {
  background: #171717;
}

p {
  color: lime; 
  font-family: "Courier";
  font-size: 20px;
  margin: 10px 0 0 10px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 30em;  
}

.type {
  animation: type 4s steps(60, end); 
}

@keyframes type{ 
  from { width: 0; } 
}
```

```html
<p id="name"></p>
```

Comment: how if I want to fade in the result?

Comment: @Rian awesome, np